# Maximum APDU size in host card emulation. Can it be longer?

Tags: java, android, nfc, apdu, hce

I am trying to send data from an android phone in Host card emulation mode to a reader application. I do understand the maximum size of an apdu should be about 260bytes. However I need to send well beyond that (a few thousand bytes). I know I can divide the data and send it in "chunks", but I am really worried about cost of that on the general performance.Is there anyway I can send a bigger apdu than 260 bytes. I don't mind a little hack too if I have to. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question. There are 2 types of APDUs according to the maximum size of data they accommodate. Normal sized APDUs (256 bytes) and extended APDUs with payload of upto 65536 bytes. However not all smartcards and readers support the extended APDU length.

Now on the android side of things, the extended length APDUs is not supported by the Android OS. Even though most of the NFC controllers support it. Therefore this is a software limitation and not a hardware one. See the 
       getMaxTransceiveLength method in
 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/master/nci/src/com/android/nfc/dhimpl/NativeNfcManager