# Host Card Emulation - Character Length

Tags: android, ios, nfc, hce

I think about a NFC solution in my Android / iOs App where I want to send a long String over a HCE to the other smartphone. But I don't know what the max. character length of a HCE in a mobile App is. Also my knowledge in this field is very low.

It would be awesome if someone could help me figure this out!

Comment: iOS apps cannot access host card emulation capabilities.

Comment: Oh! Thought new iOs made all NFC related functions public. I googled and now I see it too...Thanks for the information!

Comment: Yes, with Core NFC you can read and write NFC tags but not emulate a card.

Comment: Better off with Bluetooth/Wfi Direct to send data

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278862/maximum-apdu-size-in-host-card-emulation-can-it-be-longer gives some answers